# Back button restores modified text Views

Tags: java, android

I will simplify my code to address the problem specifically:

I have an activity A with some TextViews, which text is set to certain key values stored in SharedPreferences, in the activity's OnCreate method. Each textview has a button besides it. When a button is clicked it opens a new activity B which displays an adapter with different text strings. When the user clicks one, the new string is stored in preferences and the user is directed back to Activity A through an intent, and so OnCreate method is called and the textview is updated with the selected text. This works perfectly.

However, my problem is:
When a user does this and updates the textview, if they press Back button once, it will take them to Activity B, but if pressed twice that will take them to Activity A before updating the TextView and thus displaying the old textview, despite having stored in SharedPreferences the updated value. How can this be fixed?

A more simplified version of my problem is, I have a TextView in my layout, and a button which if pressed, deletes it and refreshes the Activity. User presses the delete button, text view disappears, but then presses back button and TextView is restored. That's what I dont want.

I have researched all the back button methodologies and savedInstanceState documentation but I still havent found something that works. I also tried adding an UpNavigation button in my action bar but it does the same effect than the back button.

ACTIVITY A (All these bits of code are called in OnCreate)

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    String sound1name = prefs.getString("sound1", "1");

TextView sound1TV = findViewById(R.id.sound1);
    sound1TV.setText(sound1Name);

 ImageView sound1btn = findViewById(R.id.sound1_btn);
    sound1btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SoundSelector.class);

            startActivity(intent1);
        }
    });
```

ACTIVITY B (calls adapter)

```
AudioFileAdapter aFilesAdapter = new AudioFileAdapter(SoundSelector.this, audioFileList, soundID);
    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.sounds_list);
    listView.setAdapter(aFilesAdapter);
```

ADAPTER IN ACTIVITY B (OnClickListener when text is selected)

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(contextL);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("sound1", sound1string);
                    editor.apply();
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(getContext(), SoundEditor.class);
                    con.startActivity(intent1);
```

Im not sure if it is the Activity Lifecycle I have to modify, or intents, or something else but if someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it, if you need any more information or code I'll post as soon as possible.

Comment: I think you need to finish the view. 

just initialize `finish();` after startActivity(intent)

Comment: @Sayem Yes!! I had Override the OnBackPressed button to finish the activity and that wasnt working so I didnt consider just adding finish after the intent, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

For storing and retrieving shared preferences try the following:

**Storing**

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("com.appname", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("sound1", "YOUR STRING HERE");
editor.apply();
```

**Retrieving**

```
SharedPreferences prfs = getSharedPreferences("com.appname", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String soundString = prfs.getString("sound1", "");
```

Your intent looks fine, are you sure you're passing Activity A's name?

For your second scenario, you could store if the text view was deleted in the shared preference, so when the back button is pressed, it won't display it again in the previous activity.

Something like this

```
if (isDeleted.equals("Yes")) {
   textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way `Activity B` is navigating back to `Activity A` by restarting the activity in the front and not by `onBackPressed()` navigation. Besides if the navigation is an important component to update the `string` value then the recommended method would be to use `startActivityForResult()` and update the preference and the `TextView` upon `onActivityResult()` of `Activity A`

```
class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity {
     private static final int activityRequest = 0x22;
     public static final String keyPref = "keyToSharedPrefData";
     private TextView mTextView;
     private boolean isHidden = false;


     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.a_activity);

         mTextView = findViewById(R.id.someTextView);
         final String textForTextView = SharedPrefUtils.getString(keyPref);
         mTextView.setText(textForTextView);

         final Button button = findViewById(R.id.someButton);

         if (button != null) {
             button.setOnClickListener((view) -> {
                 final Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, AcitivtyB.class);
                 startActivityForResult(intent, activityRequest);
             });
         }             

         final deleteButton = findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
         if (deleteButton != null) {
             deleteButton.setOnClickListener((view) -> {
                  mTextView.setText("");
                  isHidden = true;
             });
         }
     }

     @Override
     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
         if (requestCode == activityRequest && resultCode == ActivityB.resultSuccess && data != null) {
             if (data.containsKey(ActivityB.resultKey)) {
                 SharedPrefUtils.saveString(keyPref,
                     data.getString(ActivityB.resultKey, SharedPrefUtils.getString(keyPref));

                 if (mTextView != null) {
                     mTextView.setText(SharedPrefUtils.getString(keyPref));
                 }
             }
         }
         if (isHidden) {
             mTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
         } 
     }

}
```

in `ActivityB` you can

```
class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final int resultSuccess = 0x11
    public static final int resultFailure = 0x33
    public static final String resultKey = "keyForResult"         

    private void onListItemClick(final String soundString) {
        // optional you can also do this
        SharedPrefUtils.saveString(ActivityA.keyPref, soundString);

        // better to do this
        final Intent returnIntent = getIntent() != null ? getIntent() : new Intent();

        returnIntent.putExtra(resultKey, soundString);
        if (getCallingActivity() != null) {
            setResult(returnIntent, resultSuccess);
        }
        onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: OK I get what you are doing, I had never used startActivityForResult() before and I now understand much better how it works and why you would use it. However I could fix my problem by just calling finish after the intents so the back button no longer takes me to an old version of the activity, (I thought thats what back button does but apparently it doesn't finish the activity directly, only if phone needs memory)

Comment: Yes that's by design, because you might have existing references in the previous activity that if required again doesn't have to go through the re-creation cycle. Calling **finish()** manually would cause an end to the lifecycle by calling **onDestory()** subsequently on that Activity and its holding fragments. So you have use it cautiously else you might end up with dangling or null-pointer references